# Find all places where intellij cannot resolve symbol?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using intellij as editor for building grails application. I would like to find all places where intellij cannot resolve symbol. Is there an easy way to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible for groovy. I've created a request for this, feel free to track the [IDEA-198175](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198175).